# TimeStamp Column for each appended .csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have written a working code to look in a folder and select the most recent .csv and concat it to a .db. I want to insert a column with the time stamp for every .csv that is created.

Right now it changes the time stamp for for the entire .db.

So lets say I run a cron job every minute and it produces 5 rows in a csv. I want to add the TimeStamp column for every .csv that is created so when I look at the .db I can see that these five rows were created at min1. The next 5 at min2, min3, min4 . . .

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
from datetime import datetime

folder = glob.glob("/Users/redacted/*.csv")
filepath = max(folder, key=lambda f: os.stat(f).st_ctime)

list = []
for file in folder:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col=0)

#This is my TimeStamp entry that currently changes the TimeStamp for 
#my entire .db. So it always reflects the most recent time. 
    df.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', 
    pd.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))

    list.append(df)                                                 
frame = pd.concat(list, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=True)



engine = create_engine('sqlite:////Users/redacted/test.db', 
echo=False)
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    frame.to_sql('csv2', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

For every time there is a csv created using my cron Job I want to insert a TimeStamp column for that specific csv. So csv1 has a column with a unique time stamp, csv2 has a unique TimeStamp, csv3 . . .

Comment: not tested, but try passing `index=[os.path.getmtime(filepath)]` if it's just the file create time you're after?

Comment: There isn't an argument for index. Any other suggestions?